# Do scheduled notifications survive the reintallation of the mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, expo

I'm making a calendar app in react native with expo. I was thinking about using `Notifications.scheduleNotification` to pop up a notification when the time of the events in the calendar come.

When the user **resets** the phone, at least in android, the notifications survive, and they receive the previously scheduled notification anyway. This prevents me from needing to put a `BackgroundFetch` to reschedule possibly lost notifications. Instead, I schedule them when creating the event.

But I thought: What about **reinstalling**? Will I lose the scheduled notifications on reinstall?

What's the case in **android**? And in **iOS**?

Comment: You should not receive a notification from an uninstalled app. The OS might try to send it, but since the receiver app is not available it will be skipped.

Comment: @ko100v.d I meant to ask for notifications firing **after** reinstallation. Not while uninstalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- the scheduled notifications are stored within the app's data, and when the app is uninstalled, all its data is removed.
- You can use a combination of local storage and background fetching. When the app is installed or launched, you can check the local storage for any previously scheduled notifications. If there are any, you can reschedule them using Notifications.scheduleNotification.

  ```
   import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
   import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

   async function loadScheduledNotifications() {
    const storedNotifications = await AsyncStorage.getItem('scheduledNotifications');
    if (storedNotifications) {
      const notifications = JSON.parse(storedNotifications);
      notifications.forEach(notification => {
        Notifications.scheduleNotification(notification);
      });
     }
   }

   async function saveScheduledNotification(notification) {
     const storedNotifications = await AsyncStorage.getItem('scheduledNotifications');
     let notifications = [];
     if (storedNotifications) {
       notifications = JSON.parse(storedNotifications);
     }
     notifications.push(notification);
     await AsyncStorage.setItem('scheduledNotifications', JSON.stringify(notifications));
   }

   // Usage
   Notifications.scheduleNotification(notification);
   saveScheduledNotification(notification);
  ```
- We're using AsyncStorage to store and retrieve the scheduled notifications. When a notification is scheduled, we save it to AsyncStorage. When the app is launched, we load any previously scheduled notifications and reschedule them.

Comment: AsyncStorage of an app survives the reinstallation of the app? I had this problem before where the events were not saved there after reinstalling, which was unacceptable and led me to use a local database. Anyway, I can save the notifications in the local database, sure.

Comment: By the way, is there a hook I can use to run things on install??

Comment: @Umagon Yes, AsyncStorage of an app does survive the reinstallation of the app. However, there is a catch. When you uninstall and reinstall an app, the data stored in AsyncStorage is deleted. This is because AsyncStorage is a part of the app's data and is deleted when the app is uninstalled.

To persist the data even after reinstallation, you need to use a different storage method. One option is to use a server-side database to store the data. Another option is to use a local database like SQLite.

Comment: There is something I don't quite get: when I switched from AsyncStorage to local database (I'm using PouchDB), I got my data across re-installing. I investigated online that this happens because google makes backups of app data when uninstalling, and recovers them when installing. If AsyncStorage was saved in my app's data, the same should have happened. Also, if scheduled notifications were inside the app's data, they wouldn't be gone either when re-installing, since google backup would have recovered them upon installation. I'm kind of lost here. Do you have any source from where I can read?